# $x^2+4xy-2xz-5y^2+6yz-3z^2\leq 0$ $\forall (x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was thinking to check that the maximum is attached at a negative value, the function $f(x,y,z)=x^2+4xy-2xz-5y^2+6yz-3z^2$ is concave and so the local maximum is a global maximum, but how do I check that this function is concave?

Answer (score 1):

no. this is an indefinite quadratic form. No maximum and no minimum. Not convex or concave

$$  f(t,0,0) = t^2, $$
$$  f(0,t,0) = -5 t^2 $$

the Gram matrix, half the Hessian, is 
$$
G =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 2 & -1 \\
2 & -5 & 3 \\
-1 & 3 & -3
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The eigenvalues are all real but irrational, therefore cannot be written down nicely, this is Casus Irreducibilis. However, one is positive and two negative, which follows from the characteristic polynomial $x^3 + 7 x^2 -7 x - 11.$

In fact, if
$$
Q =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & -2 & -1/9 \\
0 & 1 & 5/9 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right),
$$
then
$$
Q^TG Q =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -9 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -11/9
\end{array}
\right),
$$
confirming one positive eigenvalue and two negative by [Sylvester's Law of Inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_law_of_inertia)

> Let $A$ be a symmetric square matrix of order $n$ with real entries. Any
>   non-singular matrix $S$ o the same size is said to transform $A$ into
>   another symmetric matrix $B = SAS^T$, also of order $n$, where $S^T$ is the
>   transpose of $S$. It is also said that matrices $A$ and $B$ are congruent.
>   If $A$ is the coefficient matrix of some quadratic form of $\mathbb R^n$, then $B$ is
>   the matrix for the same form after the change of basis defined by $S$.
>
> A symmetric matrix $A$ can always be transformed in this way into a
>   diagonal matrix $D$ ...... Sylvester's law of inertia states that the
>   number of diagonal entries of each kind is an invariant of $A$, i.e. it
>   does not depend on the matrix $S$ used.

Or, using $Q^{-1},$ we can write
$$ (x + 2y-z)^2 - 9 (y - \frac{5z}{9})^2 - \frac{11}{9} z^2 =x^2+4xy-2xz-5y^2+6yz-3z^2$$